# How to download all the images from the website in order, naming them from 1 to 1000

Tags: javascript, python, html, url

I want to download all the jpg and png images from the website but I need them to download in order and maybe if it's possible naming them during the download. For example download 1000 images, in order from 1 to 1000 with the name of order. For example 3rd picture will be named 3, or 300 picture will be named 300. I'm newbie in coding and I need this for my project. I can download them manually, but it will take time and I want to learn how to automate such process.

Comment: if page doesn't use JavaScript to add images then you can use `requests` or `urllib` to get HTML and later `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` to search elements in HTML. And when you find urls to images then you can use again `requests` or `urllib` to download images. And you can use some (global) variable to enumerate files and use this number to rename file. OR use `for number, url in enumerate(list_of_urls_to_images):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following approach

```
# IMPORT LIBRARIES
# choose libraries to be used

def download_images_from_url(url):
    count = 1  # initialize counter
    # loop
    
        # write code to download the image from website
    
        # write code to store it locally
    
        #  rename the image using count variable
        
    count+=1 #update counter
    
url = "https://www.website.com"
download_images_from_url(url)
```